# Method 'read' overrides nothing

Tags: scala, type-parameter

I am new to Scala Type Parameter

Below is the scala code,

```
  trait Pet {
    val name: String
  }

  class Cat(val name: String) extends Pet
  class Dog(val name: String) extends Pet
  trait Reader[T <: Pet]
  case class FileReader[T <: Pet](t : T) extends Reader[T]
  case class URLReader[T <: Pet](t : T) extends Reader[T]

  trait Process[R <: Reader[_]] {
    def read[T <: Pet](reader: Reader[T]):Seq[T]
  }

  val file= new Process[FileReader[_]]() {
    override def read[T <: Pet](reader: FileReader[T]): Seq[T] = {
      Seq.empty
    }
  }

  val url= new Process[URLReader[_]]() {
    override def read[T <: Pet](reader: URLReader[T]): Seq[T] = {
      Seq.empty
    }
  }
}
```

Why can't I pass FileReader and URLReader to read() function?

It shows the error as **Method 'read' overrides nothing**

Answer (score 3):

> Why can't I pass FileReader and URLReader to read() function?

You can, because they are both compatible with `Reader[T]`:

```
def read[T <: Pet](reader: Reader[T]): Seq[T]
```

What you can't do is override a function that takes `Reader[T]` with a function that takes `FileReader[T]` because the compiler can't guarantee that `read` is only ever called with instances of `FileReader[T]`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are a bit confused about how to abstract over a type of kind `* -> *` like `Reader`

This is the fix you need:

```scala
trait Process[R[x <: Pet] <: Reader[x]] {
  def read[P <: Pet](reader: R[P]): List[P]
}
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/6whpkNTaTcChpwEi3F03fw/3)*

Comment: Amazing, its working. Thank you.